# Python 3 from Python.org: pros and cons

Tags: homebrew, python, macos

I am trying to use [QGis](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) but sadly it needs not simply Python 3, but the [python.org](https://www.python.org/) install -- nothing else will do.  QGis in not available in the latest version either via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) nor [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/fedster/dashboard), which is a right PITA.  I do not normally use Python, but I like the fact stuff like homebrew or anaconda can be removed altogether in a clean and safe way, and can be kept up-to-date in an equally clean and safe way.  So, aside from the advantage I can install QGis, what are the SNAFUs to look out for if I go the python.org route?

Comment: I wish I knew the answer since I have the same situation.  There are online courses I'm doing that only use anaconda, and QGIS only uses python.org.  I'm sure I had something else that wanted to see homebrew.  This along with the 2.7 v 3.x has been the biggest hassle to starting to use Python more.

Part of the solution seems to be in using virtualenv and pyenv to keep things separated.